# aoss is preventing file logging - logging argument commands

Tags: logging, sound-card, alsa

I am using an application which requires [aoss](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/aoss.1.html). The results are required to be appended to a file. When I write these commands, the file is always empty:

```
aoss multimon -a DTMF | tee test.txt
aoss multimon -a DTMF > test.txt
aoss multimon -a DTMF >> test.txt
```

I believe the problem is that the file logging is pointing to `aoss`, rather than `multimon -a DTMF`, because the latter is actually an argument to the first. Is there a way to log the argument command instead, and yet still make the application runnable? (`multimon -a DTMF` is a terminal command using an application called multimon for DTMF decoding)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the entire `multimon` command into a shell script and run that with `aoss`, or start another shell inside `aoss`:

```
(shell 1) $ aoss bash
(shell 2) $ multimon -a DTMF > test.txt
(shell 2) $ exit
(shell 1) $
```

Comment: Neither of them worked sadly. This is what I wrote in the script: `#!/bin/sh

multimon -a DTMF > test.txt

exit

# END`

Answer (score 0):

The way `aoss` (a very short shell script) works is by preloading a special library using `LD_PRELOAD`. You can set this variable manually as well:

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libaoss.so'
multimon --etc --etc --etc > test.txt
```

---

> I believe the problem is that the file logging is pointing to `aoss`, rather than `multimon -a DTMF`, because the latter is actually an argument to the first.

That's not the cause. When process X opens or closes files (e.g. sets up redirection) and starts process Y, then the new process **inherits** the newly opened files. In other words, the shell just sets up redirection and runs the given `aoss multimon...` command, which inherits the redirected output from the shell. Likewise, when *aoss* does its thing and finally runs `multimon -a DTMF`, the *multimon* process inherits the same redirections from *aoss*.

Comment: I was indeed looking for a similar solution to yours! However, `export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libaoss.so'` doesn't seem to fix the problem, as `multimon -a DTMF` still wouldn't work without `aoss`. I'm getting `open: No such file or directory`

Comment: @AhmedFarid: Then read the `aoss` script and check what it does differently.